# Passing Multiple Check-box Values

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a simple html form using check boxes:

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
    <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="t1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="t2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="t3">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Currently, if I check multiple boxes and click submit, the server side gets an array like so:

```
[t1,t2,t3]
```

But I want the server to POST for each checkbox. For example, if I have all 3 boxes checked, I want the server to POST "value=t1" then POST again for "value=t2" and so on and so forth.
Any ideas?

Comment: so you want `["value=t1","value=t2","value=t3"]`  ?

Comment: why do u need to post for each checkbox?when you submit, its for the entire form.

Comment: No I want to POST 3 separate times for each Checkbox. So it would be like checking the first box and clicking submit, then checking the second box and clicking submit, and then checking the third box and clicking submit

Comment: If you have different names for checkbox type, it would send the data as - chbboxname1=val1&chbboxname2=val2&chbboxname3=val3

Comment: check my answer i thinks is that you need @user3272303

Comment: why do you need it to post 3 separate times? why don't you just process the post data 3 times instead?

Comment: I am trying to send this information to another server

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `test[]=t1&test[]=t2&test[]=t3` in the raw post body. PHP's simply processing it into an array because you've got `[]` in the name.

If you don't want an array, then don't use the `[]`. You'll get a raw post of `test=t1&test=t2&test=t3`, but `$_POST['test']` will contain **ONLY** `t3`, because that'll be the LAST value in the post body for that particular key name.

Comment: ah yes. true enough. but either way, putting `[]` in the field name makes php create an array of values, whether it's post or get.

Comment: `No I want to POST 3 separate times for each Checkbox. So it would be like checking the first box and clicking submit, then checking the second box and clicking submit, and then checking the third box and clicking submit`. this is what he want.

Comment: not possible. you'd need javascript to submit 3 times, and each submission would be independent of the others.

Comment: tell to OP. i just mentioned.

Comment: Ok I see, javascript... I need the arrays there otherwise the server will only receive the last checked value

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a new function for example

```
myArray = [t1,t2,t3];
for (var j in myArray){
   dynamicPost()
}

function dynamicPost(val){
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
     url: url+val,
     data: data,
     success: success,
     dataType: dataType
});
}
```

in this way you create new post for each value. i will it works, or if you receive this array in your backend is the same procees you need to create a for and make your process for each value, if i have more information i will help you more

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
<input type="checkbox" name="value1" value="t1">
<input type="checkbox" name="value2" value="t2">
<input type="checkbox" name="value3" value="t3">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Try using different names for each checkbox

Comment: It seems that he wants to submit each action on a checkbox in a separate HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you are trying to achieve cannot be done in PHP only but with the help of some javascript magic that will listen for check/uncheck event of each of your checkbox and then send an ajax request. Here is how can do this:

Change the checkbox names and make them unique with a common class:

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
  <input type="checkbox" name="test1" value="t1" class="checkIt">
  <input type="checkbox" name="test2" value="t2" class="checkIt">
  <input type="checkbox" name="test3" value="t3" class="checkIt">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And then listen for checkbox event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.checkIt').bind('click', function() {
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    var value = $(this).val();
    var status;
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      status = 'checked';
      // checkbox is checked
      console.log("Checkbox is checked. Name: " + name + " Value: " + value);


    } else {
      status = 'unchecked';
      // checkbox is not checked
      console.log("Checkbox is NOT checked. Name: " + name + " Value: " + value);

    }

    $.get("demo_form.asp?status=" + status + "&name=" + name + "&value=" + value, function(data) {
      //Your server response here
    });


  });
});
```

Here is a fiddle for you to play:(Open up your console)

https://jsfiddle.net/ismaakeel/ejscjw3y/4/